# Jekyll+Github pages: How to use `remote_theme` for a specific revision of the theme code

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I found a jekyll theme I like which is hosted on github (theme page info [here](https://pmarsceill.github.io/just-the-docs/)). The theme supports configuring my theme on github pages with the `remote_theme` key in `_config.yaml`, but I'm uncomfortable letting a third party's repository control the appearance and client-side code of my site.

Assuming there's a particular revision of theme files that I've audited and I'm satisfied with, how do I make sure that this revision gets used?

Some ideas:

1. Can I fork the theme repo and use `remote_theme: myaccount/my-fork`.
2. Can the `remote_theme` syntax support a particular revision hash?
3. Is using `remote_theme` simply equivalent to copying all the theme data inside my repo `_layout` and `_style` folders?

Answer (score 6):

From [the docs](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-remote-theme#declaring-your-theme) you can use an `@GITREF` syntax to use a specific branch/tag/commit

> You may also optionally specify a branch, tag, or commit to use by appending an @ and the Git ref (e.g., benbalter/retlab@v1.0.0 or benbalter/retlab@develop). If you don't specify a Git ref, the master branch will be used

Comment: thanks! that’s perfect. I missed that crucial bit of info. Please include the link in your post if you have it handy.

Comment: @init_js I added the link